# Securing authentication secrets in Azure Key Vault for Static Web App

Tags: authentication, azure-keyvault, azure-static-web-app

Adding application setting by using Key Vault Uri does not work for Static Web App. It does perfectly work for Azure Function app though.
Here is what I am doing for my static web app.

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=<KEY-VAULT-SECRET-URI>)
```

As soon as I refer key vault uri, application stop working with a 500 error. If I put hardcoded value, it does work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the `framework` and `version` you are using?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, based on [this](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/428) it's only possible if you're using Bring Your Own Functions feature.

I was debating with the same difficulty when I found that.